# Stochastic matrix is a continuous linear transformation

Tags: matrices, continuity, stochastic-processes, normed-spaces

I try to solve the following two exercises: Notice that $A$ is an $N$ by $N$ matrix and $x$ is a vector in $\mathbb{R^n}$.  I want to show that the linear transformation $$ A x=x$$ is continuous.

Therefore I have to do:

[image]

I solved the first one like this:
$$ ||Ax||_1 \leq ||A||_1 \cdot ||x||_1 = 1 \cdot ||x||_1 $$

But I have no idea how to use it to show that its continuous. Do I have to use the normal $\epsilon$-$\delta$ criteria?

Thanks for helping!

Comment: When showing $f$ is continuous, it makes sense to start by looking at $\|f(x)-f(y)\|$ for arbitrary $x,y$.  In this case, what can you say about $\|Ax-Ay\|$?

Comment: So maybe I can rewrite it as $\|A(x-y)\| \leq \|A \|  \|x-y\|=\|x-y\|$

Comment: so can i choose $\delta = \epsilon $ ?

Comment: Yes, that works.